# jquery dynamic selector from data attribute

Tags: jquery

Please see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/philphil/q71tys4g/1/

I want to do something akin to replacing `cascade1` in the **JQuery script** with a variable that reads the value from `data-cascade` in the **HTML**.

I right now `.cascade1` is hardcoded in the selector of my **jquery** script `input:checkbox.cascade1` but I want to have that value ('cascade1') dynamically loaded based on whatever is in the **HTML** element `data-cascade=cascade1`. That way my page would cascade both `cascade1` and cascade2 checkboxes properly.

I was hoping there is an easy way to do it using `data("cascade")` but I can't find it.

**html**

```
<div class="grades">
    cascade1 <input type="checkbox" data-cascade="cascade1" value="1" />
    cascade2 <input type="checkbox" data-cascade="cascade2" />
    1 <input class="cascade1" type="checkbox" />
    1 <input class="cascade1" type="checkbox"  />
    2 <input class="cascade2" type="checkbox"  />
    2 <input class="cascade2" type="checkbox"  />
    2 <input class="cascade2" type="checkbox"  />
    1 <input class="cascade1" type="checkbox"  />
</div>
```

**js**

```
$('input:checkbox[data-cascade]').change(function() {
    if($(this).prop('checked') === true) {
        $('input:checkbox.cascade1').prop('checked', true);
    } else {
        $('input:checkbox.cascade1').prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```

Comment: I see no `cascade` in your code.

Comment: It is really not clear what you are looking for. `$('input[name="pass"]')` ??? `<input type="checkbox" date-toggle="pass" value="pass" />`???

Comment: The question and code seem completely unrelated.

Comment: Very sorry I didn't update my link correctly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to do, you'd like to select an element(s) based upon data attached to another element.

Let's say you have the following:

```
<div id='someDiv' data-cascadeId='myCascadeElement'>content</div>
<div id='#myCascadeElement'>such cascade wow</div>
```

You could retrieve this value and use it to query dom like this:

```
$(function() {
    var selector = $('#someDiv')[0].dataset.cascadeId;
    $(selector).css('background-color', 'yellow');
})
```

**does this help, or is that not what you asked?**

## update

these should be the results you're looking for.

html:

```
<div class="grades">
    cascade1 <input type="checkbox" data-cascade="cascade1" value="1" />
    cascade2 <input type="checkbox" data-cascade="cascade2" />
    1 <input class="cascade1" type="checkbox" />
    1 <input class="cascade1" type="checkbox"  />
    2 <input class="cascade2" type="checkbox"  />
    2 <input class="cascade2" type="checkbox"  />
    2 <input class="cascade2" type="checkbox"  />
    1 <input class="cascade1" type="checkbox"  />
</div>
```

js:

```
$(function() {
    $('input:checkbox[data-cascade]').change(function() {
        var selector = $(this).data('cascade'),
            isChecked = $(this).prop('checked');
        $('.'+selector).prop('checked', isChecked);
    });
});
```

Comment: I will work through what you answered, although I don't understand it yet. please see my updated question, I hope it is more clear.

Comment: yes this is what I was asking thanks, I am working through now to get it to work.

Comment: I marked your answer correct but also posted what I did in case other people are curious to see more clearly the solution.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/q71tys4g/3/ Check that out. I think it's what you want and it's pretty slick.

Comment: That link you posted mine hahah :)

Comment: I am just realizing now that you are the mystery person...I am so slow. Thanks:)

Comment: I'm the dude who answered the question originally. lol. I'll take mysterious, though. glad to help.

Comment: ha. oh, maybe I'm the slow one... you'd already determined that.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing.

```
$('input:checkbox[data-cascade]').change(function() {
    var selector = $(this).data("cascade");

    if($(this).prop('checked') === true) {
        $('input:checkbox.'+selector).prop('checked', true);
    } else {
        $('input:checkbox.'+selector).prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```